# using ng repeat to create a second row only underneath the primary row

Tags: angularjs

I want to repeat data in a table row. However, when i click a button in the last td of the row, I want Another row to show underneath it, and ONLY beneath that element.

I can repeat separate data using ng-repeat-show/end, but it repeats the secondary data over all the primary data rows. The code:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-responsive">


        <tr ng-repeat-start="data in product_data | filter:'Flexi Floor/Low Wall':true">
            <td style="vertical-align:middle;">{{data.model_no_from}} + {{data.model_no_to}}</td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle;">{{data.cooling}}</td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle;">{{data.heating}}</td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle;"><span class="blue">{{data.nominal_cooling}}</span><span class="red">{{data.nominal_heating}}</span></td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle;">{{data.pipe_length}}</td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle;">{{data.system_listPrice | currency:"&#163;"}}</td>
            <td class="td_button"><button class="btn btn-default btn-block td_button_border" ng-click="add()">Select</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="show_row">
            <td colspan="6">This will repeat</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you show the desired output you need in a table format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a plunker example of what I think you're looking for: http://plnkr.co/edit/z7gYsKxNffwm78aiEgQX?p=preview

Basically if you model your table rows as an array of objects, the addRow() button click function should insert a new row object into your model and when Angular applies changes to the view, ng-repeat will take care of appending the new row.

So if this is the ng-repeat row of your table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
  <td>{{$index}}</td>
  <td>{{row.details}}</td>
  <td><button ng-click="addRow($index)">Add Row</button></td>
</tr>
```

Then this addRow() function and model should accomplish what you're after:

```
$scope.rows = [
  { details: 'Originally row 0' },
  { details: 'Originally row 1' },
  { details: 'Originally row 2' }
];

$scope.addRow = function(index){
  $scope.rows.splice( index+1, 0, { details: 'new row after clicking index '+index} );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the plunk, i will take a look at this tomorrow.

Comment: @JoshWinters did the answer answer your question ?